# MFC CPen::CreatePen line width

Tags: c++, mfc, drawing, line

How to determine the width of line to set in constructor or in CPen::CreatePen in cases:

1. If I display image for example at scale 60% and I need that my line was 1mm on screen.
2. If I want my line width to be 0.01% of image max(width,height)

Comment: In such cases I always work is anisotropic mapping modes. In this case the GDI does all the rest for me.

Comment: @xMRi can you provide example how it can be done using mapping mode?

Comment: As an introduction it is sufficient. Also read the MSDN about mapping modes. The idea is to separate between internal logical units and external device units. Using anisotropic mapping modes you can leave all calculations up to the GDI. You only have to convert from internal to external coordinates and vice versa. DPtoLP, LPtoDP. I hope this is all covered here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/doc_view/scrolling/article.php/c3345/Add-Zoom-and-Scale-Capabilities-to-CScrollView.htm

Comment: @xMRi this article is about how to scale, but I don't need to scale segment I need to set width(thickness) of segment depending on image size (length of segment is the same).

Comment: But this is "scaling" from my Point of view. Just calculate it by yourself. You want the line 0,01%. So just calculate max(1,currentHeight/10000) this is exactly 0.01% of the height. And beacuse currentHeight is height*scale (0,6 for 60%) you have imageHeight*scale/10000... But again. I beleive that using mapping modes everything is easier.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the type of CPen's width is int, so you have to use integer type.

If you use second plan, below code is available, however, you have to concern about type and value of width.

```
CImage image;   

float max_value = static_cast<float>(max(image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()));

//get value for 1%
float pen_width = max_value * 0.01f;

CPen pen(PS_SOLID, static_cast<int>(pen_width), RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: what it's actually mean by pen_width = 1? is it mean that on image it will be 1 pixel thick? and if pen_width= n   =>   n pixel thick?

Comment: If width is 0, it is always 1 pixel regardless of the mapping mode. Otherwise, it depends on the mapping mode. [Mapping mode](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~reckert/360/14a_map_modes_f03.html), [CPen - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ykez8tds.aspx)

Comment: but I think mapping mode can only affect on geometry of primitives but not on pen width.

Comment: and what if we use MM_TEXT mode when each logical unit maps to one device unit? if we create line with width = 3 is that means that it will be 3 pixel width result?